# Google Earth Engine - count non-null values of multiple images and return them as numbers

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to get quality information for clipped images in an ImageCollection. My approach - so far - was to mask each image and then count the amount of remaining pixels by using "ee.Reducer.count()" and add the result as metadata to each Image.

The problem is that the new metadata "pixel_amount" is cast as a Dictionary and I can't get its numerical values to sort by them or print them as a list.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/42e32bd20eddb3a5a9fb0852306c967c

```
/////////// GEOMETRY //////////////////////////////////////////////
var potsdam = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[12.884230720121536, 52.48090537979447],
          [12.884230720121536, 52.2897995867844],
          [13.234419929105911, 52.2897995867844],
          [13.234419929105911, 52.48090537979447]]], null, false);

/////////// CLOUDMASK /////////////////////////////////////////////

function maskclouds(image){
var qa = image.select('BQA');
  var mask_1 =       qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4)
                 .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 6))
                 .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 8))
                 .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 10))
                 .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 12));
  var mask_2 = mask_1.eq(0);
  var mask = ee.Image(mask_2);
  return image.updateMask(mask)
              .select("B.*")
              .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

/////////// SEARCH DATE /////////////////////////////////////////////

var start = '2016-04-01'
var end = '2016-10-31'
var diff = ee.Date(start).advance(28, 'day').millis().subtract(ee.Date(start).millis());
var list = ee.List.sequence(ee.Date(start).millis(), ee.Date(end).millis(), diff);

/////////// GET IMAGES /////////////////////////////////////////////

function get_images (date) {
  var date2 = ee.Date(date)
var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
    .filterBounds(potsdam)
    .filterDate(date2, date2.advance(28, 'day'))
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    //.filter(ee.Filter.eq('TARGET_WRS_PATH', 193))
    .map(maskclouds)
    .first()

        return image
}

var LS8 = list.map(get_images)
var LS8_IC = ee.ImageCollection(LS8).limit(10)

/////////// CLIP IMAGES AND COUNT PIXEL /////////////////////////////////////////////

function clip_count_f (image) {
  var clipped = image.clip(potsdam)

    var unmasked_pixels =  clipped.select('B4').reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
      geometry: potsdam,
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e9
      });  

        var image1 = clipped.set('pixel_amount', unmasked_pixels)  

  return image1
}

/////////// CAST TO LIST AND VISUALIZE /////////////////////////////////////////////

var clipped = ee.ImageCollection(LS8_IC.map(clip_count_f)) //.sort('pixel_amount')
var clipped_list = clipped.toList(LS8_IC.size())
print(clipped_list)

Map.setCenter(13.0609, 52.3873, 11)

Map.addLayer(ee.Image(clipped_list.get(6)), {bands:['B5', 'B2', 'B3'], min:8000 ,max:18000}, 'LS8_clipped')
print(clipped)
```

Comment: Your assets are private so no one will be able to run your script.

Comment: Also, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253455/google-earth-engine-extract-values-from-featurecollection-as-list

Comment: I fixed it, it was the wrong link to begin with.

Comment: Also I tried ".aggregate_array" before, but the result is still a list of Objects that I can't really work with (I can't sort them or cast them to ee.Number).